# Crossed hand gesture

Tags: negation, non-verbal-communication

I was watching a Korean commercial and the actress makes a gesture by crossing her hands:

[image: korean crossed hand gesture]

What does this gesture mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has negative meaning. (here 아닙니다=It's not.)

Comment: This woman is crossing her hands at the wrist. A similar, smaller gesture is to cross the hands at the first joint of the fingers (that is, the one closest to the palms).

Answer (score 2):

She says "no" with her body language. Crossing one's hands looks like X.